# How can I manage a method after touching leftBarButtonItem in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I was using simple UINavigationController.
but If I come from sub viewController, I want to occur a some custom event.

For example,
If rootViewController is AA
and subviewController of AA is BB.
and then enter the BB (by pushViewController).

and then, BB->AA.
this time, I want to manage a event.

currently, I made it view UIBarButtonItem, but Its shape is RECT. (I want pentagon)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In BB's `-viewWillDisappear:`, set a global flag.

Then in AA's `-viewWillAppear:`, check if the global flag is set. If yes, manage your event, then clear the flag.

Comment: I know these methods but my app not use them. Thank you anyway ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Make BB become the delegate of the UINavigationController AA and BB are in. Then implement the `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` delegate method and check if the viewController passed in is AA.